# Is there a way to determine a line from which XHR was issued in firebug or web inspector?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug, xmlhttprequest, web-inspector

Is there a way to determine a line and filename from which XHR was issued in Firebug or Web Inspector (maybe Opera Dragonfly/IE Developers Toolbar)?  If there isn't, what is the best way to find that out? Just searching the codebase for the URI called? (often it will be constructed, though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Developer Tools(chrome) you can set breakpoints for any XHR from the Script tab.

- Script Tab
- XHR Breakpoints(on right hand side)
- Click the + and press return
- A new item will be added saying "Any XHR"
- Run the script and it will break on any XHR :-)

Answer (score 1):

For Firebug you can start with
http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html