# How to find which javascript code fired ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging, firebug

Is there any quick way to find out which javascript code (file name and exact line) fired a particular ajax call?

Using firebug i can locate the ajax call but finding out the exact line quickly will help to debug

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154447/is-there-a-way-to-determine-a-line-from-which-xhr-was-issued-in-firebug-or-web-i ?

Comment: @Simon Lindholm you are right. I'm sorry when I searched SO before posting this question, couldn't find that link. Now I got what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In Firebug you can either click the source link in the Console panel:

[image: console xhr source link]

or set a breakpoint in the Net panel:

[image: net xhr breakpoint]

Answer (score 2):

If you put a breakpoint in your code at the point of this ajax call, the debugger will show you the stack of function calls.

See this from [Chrome developer tools documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints) :

[image]

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. My intention is to find out the exact line which fires this ajax. I'm debugging code developed others. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I see what part is missing. Maybe I don't understand what you mean by "locate the ajax call". Can you detail this point ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know any clean method (maybe there exists one). But I have a little hack to propose.

If you are not using Prototype.js in your webpage, enter these commands in the command line (with Firebug 1.11):

```
window.old$ = $; // in case you're using a framework like jQuery
include("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"); // loads Prototype
```

The console should print: *prototype.js properly included.*

Then, to restore your old "$" variable, type:

```
window.$ = window.old$;
```

Now that Prototype is loaded, we can wrap the XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open function, so we can get the call stack (just like suggested dystroy):

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open.wrap(function(orig, ...args)
{
    console.log("trace for :"+args[1]); // prints the URL of the request
    console.trace(); // prints the stack trace
    orig.apply(null, args); // call the original function
});
```

And that's it.

N.B.: if the request is launched at start:

- in the Script panel, set a breakpoint on the first JS instruction of your webpage
- execute the commands above in the Console panel
- go back to the Script panel, and click on continue

Answer (score -1):

what I usually do is adding a bunch of:

```
console.log("message that explains where in the code I am now...");
```

but pay attention, because console.log can create problems with older version of IE, you have to remove all console.log calls when you go in production.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But here I'm debugging other's code. :-)